# Invalid char error when running .awk file

Tags: awk

I am appending a value `100` to every line in a file with the code below. This code works well when I run it in terminal but when I save the code in .awk file and run it I am getting an error. How to run this code from a script file instead of running from terminal?

```
code:  awk -F ';' '{if ($2==NULL) print $0"100"}' example.txt
```

**my.awk**

```
awk -F ';' '{if ($2==NULL) print $0"100"}'
```

**command in terminal**

```
awk -f my.awk example.txt
```

**error**

```
 invalid char ''' in expression. I get this error at ';'
```

How to rectify this error and run the awk file on example.txt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When executing an `awk` script with `awk -f`, the script should *only* contain the `awk` code.

In your case

```
{if ($2==NULL) print $0"100"}
```

or

```
$2 == NULL { print $0 "100" }
```

You would execute this with

```
awk -F ';' -f my.awk example.txt
```

If you want to set `FS` to `;` in the script (statically, instead of on the command line with `-F`), do so in a `BEGIN` block:

```
BEGIN { FS = ";" }

$2 == NULL { print $0 "100" }
```

Note, too, that the variable `NULL` is unset in your code.

Comment: Ok. Got it. Thanks. What is meant by `NULL` is unset? I did not understand that line.

Comment: @Laxman You are using a variable called `NULL` that you haven't given any value.  If you want to test whether `$2` is empty, just use `$2 == ""`.